# Как подписаться на http запрос в Angular2?

Tags: angular2

В компоненте есть Iframe, который делает http запрос.
В DevTools запрос виден.

Есть ли возможность подписаться на этот запрос, ведь инициатор запроса не сам Angular, а Iframe?

Comment: `iframe` с какогор домена загружается? С того же самого, что и главная страница?

Comment: Нет. Сторонний домен

Comment: Тогда никак. И вам здесь ни Angular ни что-либо другое не поможет)